# Which Service Account should I use in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I'm a newbie in SSRS, so my experiences are limited in this topic. In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, there are several options to set the Service Account. I have the option to either use a built-in account or another account. The dropdown menu gives me the following four options:

- Local System
- Network Service
- ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS
- Local Service

Now I'm a bit confused which entry should I use and what their purpose is. Could you point me to a resource where this "concept" is described? In which situation should I use which one? When should I use "Use another account"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) when setting up services and create a specific account for each service. If you are going to use built-in accounts, which one you should select depends if you are using Active Directory or not. If the server is in an AD Domain, you should use Network. Otherwise, I'd suggest Local System.

But my first choice would be to create a specific service account in active directory for the service.

Comment: Creating a specific service account is the right answer. Additionally, life is good when your service accounts follow a consistent naming convention. Example: username `svc_ssrs`, first name `SQL Server Reporting`, last name `Service`.

Comment: That's how I do it...and I put them in their own OU as well.

Comment: LocalSystem..."dangerous, don't use" according to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco

Answer (score 0):

My answer is Use AD account as services accounts ..you will not face any connectivity issuses etc.

Comment: If you mean use the Administrator account, that's not a good choice from a security perspective. If you mean use an Active Directory account, you need to be more specific.